# Como puedo tener acceso a un control desde un formulario hijo

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en una app Windows Forms. El problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un formulario principal en el cual tengo un panel donde llama a mis formularios los cuales son user control.

Partiendo de ahí, cuando tengo un form en el panel llamo a un formulario(forms) y desde ese formulario llamo a otro formulario(forms) desde este último mando a hacer una acción en el user contrl en el cual hay un método que me activa un control.
Mi pregunta es como puedo navegar hasta el formulario principal el cual es el piso de todo y en el cual hay un panel y dentro de ese panel mi user control que hace de formulario.

```
ucProducto uc =Panel1.Controls.OfType<ucProducto>().FirstorDefault();
if(uc != null){
uc.ActivarGrp();

}
```

No encuentro la manera de llegar al user control. Desde el formulario segundo formulario no puedo tener acceso al formulario principal.
[image: Imagen1]

[image: Imagen2]

[image: Imagen3]

[image: Imagen4]

Comment: pero cuantos saltos entre forms estas realizando ? como es eso de tener un form en el panel? no era que en el panel asignas user control?

Comment: Leandro, modifique la pregunta puse unas imagenes

Comment: no me quedo claro la ultima pantalla que seria? porque veo algo como superpuesto

Comment: Así es Leandro es un GroupBox que me contiene esos controles, gracias por la respuesta logre solucionarlo como me indicas con Singleton, excelente técnica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el form principal expone una interface podrias desde el user control acceder a este al igual que lo harias entre dos forms

Cuando instancias el user control al ponerlo en el Panel deberias en el constructor asignar la instancia del form principal, de esta forma desdeel user control tienes acceso al form que lo invoco y puedes realizar acciones.

Seria lo mismo que explico aqui

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

solo que en lugar de ser un form que muestras con show() seria un user control que asignas a un panel

```
ucProducto uc = new ucProducto(this);
//resto codigo
Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

cuando asignas el `this` seria el form principal, el cual implementa la interfaz, el resto no cambia

**>>Desde el formulario segundo formulario no puedo tener acceso al formulario principal.**

Si hay muchos forms de salto y quieres llegar al raiz de forma directa quizas la formas mas prolija sea usando eventos

[[Winforms] Singleton - Pasar datos entre formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/07/winforms-singleton-pasar-datos-entre.html)

en el articulo explico del tema, analia el titulo `2 – Eventos, Informar de cambios entre formulario`

Comment: Leandro, en el constructor de ucProducto que debo tener para pasarle como parametro ese this?

Comment: Leandro, el que implementa la interfaz es ucProducto

Comment: edite la respuesta, quizas lo que agregue resulte de ayuda