# Editar Elementos y que aparezca en otro Formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo Este codigo en c# Pero no se como puedo editar un elemento  de un combo box y que aparezca en otro combo box de otro formulario y estoy utilizando Matrizes

Formulario 1:

```
public static string[,] Auuto = new string[400, 400];
  public static int s = 0;

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    cmb_Año.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    AfinacionAdmi.Auuto[AfinacionAdmi.s, 0] = cmb_Año.Text;
    AfinacionAdmi.s++;
}
```

Formulario 2:

```
public fAfinacion(){
  InitializeComponent();
  for(int j = 0; j < AfinacionAdmi.s//Formulario 1; j++){
    cmb_Año.Items.Add(AfinacionAdmi.);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrias ser mucho mas claro en tu escenario y que queres? tu problema es pasar datos de un form a otro? eso esta contestado en el sitio muchas veces.

Comment: si ya  esta contestado en el sitio muchas veces no estaría preguntado

Comment: como por ejemplo aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18133/324 por eso te pregunte si la pregunta es esa u otra cosa. Si mi mensaje te sono rudo te pido disculpas.

Comment: Si eso no contesta tu pregunta, aclara mejor el escenario y armamos una respuesta acorde a tu problema.

Comment: Te recomiendo generar un modelo, de esa manera podrás modificarlo y consultar la información en cualquier form que desees